# find the coordinate of a point knowing three other points

Tags: trigonometry

[image]I have the WLAN nodes D,A,C,B sequenced to forward packets. D,A and B can exchange x,y, but C is unknown. the distances are known for the triangle ACB, and I used the law of cosine, to find A then used A'=acos((y2-y1)/c). next I calculated x and y by  x=x1-b*sin(A-A') and y=y1+b*cos(A-A'), simulated the results and two locations were identified as valid.enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Use the law of cosines to find one of the angles (say the one across from side $A$).  Then a trig identity to find the height of the triangle.  Then vector algebra to find the coordinates of $C$.

Comment: the figure was not clear, I updated the layout, can the law of cosine still be applied, now

Comment: but I will end up having two values  c(x,y) and c(x,-y) and I need one possible point, therefore I used D

Comment: Also, for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: is this correct--> cos A = (b^2 + c^2 − a^2) / 2bc
-->h=sinA/b
-->h • b = |h| × |b| × cos(A)
-->h • b = hx × bx + hy × by

Comment: Your first plot makes it look like $B$ should be $(250,-50)$.  Did you leave off that minus sign in your second plot?  Because that could be the source of your trouble -- your solution *will* in fact be $(50,50)$ in that case.

Comment: yes Bye_World, you are right I forgot the minus, but I wanted to have a general formula for any type of situation (different triangle shapes). is it possible to have two equations for x and y.

Comment: If you're solving this *exact* type of problem over and over, a general*ish* method (you'll get $2$ solutions instead of one) is to solve the equations $\|\vec{AC}\|= b$ and $\|\vec{BC}\|=a$.  This is just two quadratic equations in $2$ unknowns which in general will give you two solutions.  Then you have to figure out from there which of your two solutions is correct.

Comment: what about point D , dose it help

Comment: Yes, you need point $D$ to figure out which of the two solutions is the correct one.  I just can't think of a way of doing it without graphing and looking at it (I'm not used to writing algorithms).

Comment: thank you for all the help Bye_world